# Connecting to a remote MySQL database on Google app engine

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine

I'm working on an application to run on Google app engine. Normally, I would have to enable billing/pay if am using Google Cloud SQL. So for a start, I decided to connect remotely to a mysql database on another server. It works perfectly offline but after deploying my app it didn't work. Clearly, GAE doesn't support remote connections ... Is there another way to go around this ? tunneling ?

NB: Using an HTTP API to return info from my database ... would require more programing efforts.

Answer (score 7):

In [1.8.8](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes) we made it possible to use remote sockets from PHP.

You'll need to make sure your application has billing enabled for remote sockets to be available. Once you do that you should be able to connect to a remote MySQL database from your app engine app.

Comment: is this also the case from Python? I have a non-CloudSQL MySQL db I need to be able to connect to from the Python runtime.

Comment: i don't know for certain by i don't see why not - remote sockets allow you to connect to any service over tco/ip.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, App Engine does not support External calls:

> An App Engine application cannot:
>
> write to the filesystem. PHP applications can use Google Cloud Storage
>   for storing persistent files. Reading from the filesystem is allowed,
>   and all application files uploaded with the application are available.
>
> open a socket or access another host directly. An application can use
>   the App Engine URL fetch service to make HTTP and HTTPS requests to
>   other hosts on ports 80 and 443, respectively.
>
> respond slowly. A web request to an application must be handled within
>   a few seconds. Processes that take a very long time to respond are
>   terminated to avoid overloading the web server.
>
> make other kinds of system calls.

Comment: Thanks. I would trying using Cloud SQL

Comment: Now GAE supports external calls.

Answer (score 0):

What Stuart Langley said also applies to Python.

You must have bill enabled to use remote sockets. But from my experiment, the MySQLdb included with the App Engine runtime seems not working with external MySQL database.

You can use the pure python library mysql-connector-python provided by Oracle instead. But be warned, the latency is high (if you open a new connection per request the total latency can be 5 seconds plus). Maybe because the remote socket is not a native implementation but rather a proxy or service under the hook.

Comment: Hi @duan so what your telling is that you need to have billing option activated in order to make calls to external mysql db that are not part of google service like CloudSQL or others right?

Answer (score 0):

This is same issue with me, but Unfortunately I did it.

This is example of my `app.yaml`

```
runtime: php72
env_variables:
    LOG_CHANNEL: stackdriver
    ## Put production environment variables here.
    APP_KEY: YOUR_APP_KEY
    APP_STORAGE: /tmp
    VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
    SESSION_DRIVER: cookie
    ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
    DB_DATABASE: YOUR_DB_NAME
    DB_USERNAME: YOUR_DB_USERNAME
    DB_PASSWORD: YOUR_DB_PASSWORD
    DB_CONNECTION: mysql
    DB_HOST: YOUR_DB_PUBLIC_AP_ADDRESS
    DB_PORT: 3306
```

If you use remote **[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)** in `cPanel` don't forget to add access host in `cPanel` menu and the Host (% wildcard is allowed) fill usin: `%.%.%.%` and add.

And then you can fix this issue…