# Error connecting my remote mysql database to App engine

Tags: mysql, database, google-app-engine

I have a remote mysql database and I would like connect it to my app in Google app engine, but I have these errors:

```
No pudo conectarse: php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname failed. errno=0
```

These are the files:

config.php:

```
<?php 
    $host_db = "<myhost>";
    $usuario_db = "<myuser>"; 
    $clave_db = "<mypass>"; 
    $nombre_db = "<namedatabase>";
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");

    //conectamos y seleccionamos db 
    $enlace = mysql_connect($host_db, $usuario_db, $clave_db); 
    if (!$enlace) {
      die('No pudo conectarse: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db($nombre_db); 
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8mb4");
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");
?>
```

And apiv1/connect/login.php (https://argon-producer-554.appspot.com/apiv1/connect/login.php?user=test&passmd5=202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70):

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');  
session_start(); 
include('../../config.php'); 
[...]
Line 15 => mysql_query()
[...]
?>
```

PD: The app engine release is 1.9.3

Comment: are you running a paid app? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217326/connecting-to-a-remote-mysql-database-on-google-app-engine

Comment: No, it's free. Are there other way for works it?

Comment: But If I have the version 1.9.3 also?

Comment: IIRC sockets are paid and this might be trying to use that. don't know about versions.

Comment: If I connect a Mongo database (https://mongolab.com/), works it?

Comment: Doesn't work, it seems that the mongoclient extension is not installed...

Comment: My host is better than Google app engine!