# Error 1049: database unknown on deploying app on GAE python

Tags: python, mysql, database, google-app-engine, mysql-error-1049

On ubuntu, I am trying to deploy an app on GAE python. I have also connected mysql client to it through these lines:

```
if (os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE') and os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE').startswith('Google App Engine/')):
                db = MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket='/cloudsql/' + _INSTANCE_NAME, db='databaselab', user= 'root')
```

where in mysql 5.6, I have create a database named 'databaselab'. But the error on deploying it on GAE shows:

```
OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'databaselab'")
```

But when I replace 'databaselab' with predefined tables 'mysql', everything works fine. But then I thought to create required tables in 'mysql' database as I was able to access that database. But then error comes

```
Error: (1146, "mysql.table_name doesn't exist")
```

i.e I am able to access only predifined tables naming 'mysql', 'information_schema' and 'performance_schema'. Rest other databases and new tables defined in predefined databases are unknown to GAE although all those databases and tables exist.

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| databaselab       |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
```

How to resolve this ?

Comment: @MySQLRockstar Which privileges I need to grant then to be accessed?  I have created the tables by just "CREATE DATABASE " statement and tables also likewise.

Comment: I would say you have a typo on your settings with database name: `db='databaselab'` should be `db='databaselabb'`

Comment: @Anzel No, actually in the question here only i did this typo. otherwise, everywhere its 'databaselab' only.

Comment: Have you checked the user/database permissions are correct?

Comment: @Anzel on mysql now I did grant all privileges on databaselab.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'mypass'; but still same error

Comment: This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217326/connecting-to-a-remote-mysql-database-on-google-app-engine) may interest you