# Why is meekrodb class not working on google apps engine, but does work on local

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm new to google-app-engine and I'm trying to migrate a PHP site that currently uses the meekrodb class for mysql (http://www.meekro.com/) to connect to a db stored with my webhost with access enable from any IP.

When I run the site on the local app-engine instance there are no issues, but when I deploy it I get an error 500 error with the following log:

```
90.202.109.98 - - [12/Jul/2015:04:31:36 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36" "*.appspot.com" ms=145 cpu_ms=0 loading_request=1 exit_code=204 instance=00c61b117ce2904f41b4d706f60338b416a908e1 app_engine_release=1.9.23
```

The page being run was index.php and it did nothing except load up the class and DB attributes (which works fine alone), but when I add the following code:

```
DB::query('select * from places');
```

The error occurs, again, only on the remote instance.

Any thoughts on why?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, it's because my db is remotely hosted and Google doesn't allow that for free apps. I'd have to enable sockets. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20254933/1254900